# Zlib ruby - how to check if data is deflated/compressed before processing it?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, zlib

I'm in a situation where some data in a database is not compressed, but I want to enable compression for new data coming in, without having to update all records currently in the database to make them compressed as well.

So I need to be able to say, if deflated, inflate it and process it, else just process it. But I can't see how to gracefully check whether the data is already compressed before trying to process it, unless I do a 'begin ... rescue' block:

```
begin 
  process(Zlib::Inflate.inflate(data))
rescue Zlib::DataError
  process(data) 
end
```

Is there a better way? I've seen references to magic numbers and checking the first couple of bytes of the file, but no good examples of how to achieve these things in ruby. Any help appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you suggested, you could either rescue the specific exception or manually validate the file type by reading the magic numbers.

Ruby IO's [readpartial](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.2/IO.html#method-i-readpartial) can read the specified number of bytes, which you can compare with the magic number.

I personally would stick to rescuing the exception as a lot of the core libraries perform the same magic number check before raising the exception.

Answer (score 3):

What you propose is the best way.  It will very quickly determine that the first two bytes are not a zlib header.  If by accident the input data appears to be a zlib header (about a 1 in 1024 chance), then the decompression will detect an invalid deflate stream given random data within on the order of 30 bytes almost all the time.